# "pruning file" - is that my compiler or GNU Make?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

A target in my makefile looks like this:

```
.moc/moc_plmviewsetup.cpp: C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/PROJ/src/PasaHmiExtension/pasahmiextension_global.h \
        C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/PROJ/qt5binaries/include/QtCore/qglobal.h \
        C:/Users/User1/Desktop/A/QNX_SDK/target/qnx6/usr/include/stddef.h \
        ...
```

And the output of GNU `make` is:

```
  Considering target file '.obj/moc_plmviewsetup.o'.
   File '.obj/moc_plmviewsetup.o' does not exist.
    Considering target file '.moc/moc_plmviewsetup.cpp'.
     File '.moc/moc_plmviewsetup.cpp' does not exist.
      Pruning file 'C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/src/PasaHmiExtension/pasahmiextension_global.h'.
      Pruning file 'C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/HMI_FORGF/qt5binaries/include/QtCore/qglobal.h'.
      Pruning file 'C:/Users/mureadr/Desktop/A/QNX_SDK/target/qnx6/usr/include/stddef.h'.
      ...
```

- What does pruning mean?
- What is doing it: my compiler or GNU `make`?
- Why does pruning occurr?
- What is the relevance of pruning happening?

Comment: See here for details on pruning: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2007-05/msg00017.html

Comment: @djthoms good catch. I really did google this before I posted this question.

Comment: @djthoms so pruning is NOT about the prerequisites being newer than the target but merely whether the prereqs have to be rebuilt? Correct?

Comment: @djthoms do you want to post the text of that email as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Answer from GNU Make mailing lists, posted by @djthoms:](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-make/2007-05/msg00017.html)

> On Tue, 2007-05-01 at 08:41 -0700, Hiebert, Darren (MS) wrote:
>
> > What are the reasons that dependencies are pruned when evaluating
> >     whether to build a target?
>
> Hi Darren;
>
> Pruning happens when make thinks that it has already evaluated those
>   targets and determined that they are not rebuildable, AND make has not
>   run any rules so that their state could be changed since they were
>   last examined.  It's a way to short-circuit what can be a long,
>   complex computation.
>
> Without seeing your makefile it's hard to tell why your targets might
>   be considered prunable when they shouldn't be.